# save workbook in different name vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need help to develope a code in Excel VBA that save every month a new woorkbook in the same location but in a different name every month.
**It need to be without changing the code every month.**

Comment: What did you try already? can you post some code?

Answer (score 2):

Run this once each month:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As String
    s = Format(Now(), "mmmm_yyyy") & ".xlsm"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=s
End Sub
```